# How can I wait for asyncronous functions to complete before setting module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to make my app create routes based on data loaded from the database (mongodb+mongoose);

Here is what I currently have:

```
var app = express();

var articleRoute = require('./article.js');
var Articles = require('./models/articles.js');
Articles.get((err, articles) => {
    if (err) return console.log('error');

    //loop through all articles
    articles.forEach(article=> {
        app.use('/'+article.slug, articleRoute);

    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

The articles are successfully obtained, but will not be included in the app as module.exports is set before the articles are obtained from the database.

If I instead put that line in the callback like this:

```
var app = express();

var articleRoute = require('./article.js');
var Articles = require('./models/articles.js');
Articles.get((err, articles) => {
    if (err) return console.log('error');

    //loop through all articles
    articles.forEach(article=> {
        app.use('/'+article.slug, articleRoute);

    });

    module.exports = app;
});
```

Then the app actually just seems to exit, without any export being set, and I get this error message: `TypeError: app.set is not a function` which gets called from my main script like this:

```
var app = require('../app');
app.set('port', 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I highly recommend against your design where top level routes match article slugs.  This gives you NO unique namespace that doesn't potentially conflict with article slugs to create normal paths for your website pages, ajax routes, etc...  It's generally a lot cleaner when building and maintaining your site to put all the dynamic routes for article slugs under some static path such as:

```
/article
```

Then, there will not be any conflicts between article slugs and the rest of the paths that run your site.  I would also argue that it's more "REST like" since you specific the type of resource you're requesting with the top of the path and then you add the resource name as the 2nd level path.

---

> How can I wait for asynchronous functions to complete before setting module.exports

In current versions of node.js, you can't wait for an asynchronous operation to finish before setting exports.  Can't be done.  There is a proposal to allow some version of that in some future version of node.js, but it isn't here now.

Exporting and importing is synchronous.  Therefore a value obtained asynchronously is not available yet for exporting or importing.

The usual work-around is that you export a method that one can call that returns a promise or accepts a callback and you fetch the asynchronous value in that method and the caller uses the returned promise or passes in a callback and the asynchronous value is communicated back via the promise or the callback.

---

**First Version Could Work**

FYI, your first version could still work if you aren't adding generic routes that would take precedence over the routes added when the asynchronous operation completes.  The routes just won't be available on the `app` object until your asynchronous code finishes doing its job.  It's OK to export an `app` object that will have some routes added to it after the export.  That construct works, though your server will be live without all the routes attached yet and as the `articles.forEach()` finishes, the rest of the routes will be added (I presume this takes less than a couple seconds, so it's probably not a big deal).

---

**Second Version Will Not Work**

As I think you know, your second version does not work at all because assigning module.exports asynchronously doesn't work.  The caller will have already grabbed the empty `module.exports` object and won't see your `app` when you assign it later.

---

**Export an Asynchronous Method That Main Startup File Calls**

The classic way to solve this would be export a method for adding the routes:

```
const app = express();

const articleRoute = require('./article.js');
const Articles = require('./models/articles.js');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const Articles.getPromise = promisify(Articles.get);

function assignArticleRoutes() {
    return Articles.getPromise().then(articles => {
        //loop through all articles
        articles.forEach(article=> {
            app.use('/'+article.slug, articleRoute);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error loading article routes", err);
        throw err;
    });
}

module.exports = {app, assignArticleRoutes};
```

Then, call that method from your main startup file:

```
const {app, assignArticleRoutes} = require('../app');
app.set('port', 3000);

assignArticleRoutes().then(() =>> {
    // start server only after all routes have been added
    app.listen(app.get('port'));
}).catch(err => {
    // decide what to do here if article routes can't be loaded
});
```

---

**Use Single Dynamic Route for all Articles**

Another way of thinking about the problem that gives you a bit more flexibility is to use a static article prefix on your route that allows it to be pre-configured and then you load the articles upon demand.  This can work because you're already using a common request handler for all the article routes:

```
const app = express();

const articleRoute = require('./article.js');
const Articles = require('./models/articles.js');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const Articles.getPromise = promisify(Articles.get);

// load articles and save promise so we can use the promise later    
const articlesP = Articles.getPromise().then(articles => {
    const articleSet = new Set(articles);
    return articleSet;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error loading article routes", err);
    throw err;
});

app.use("/article/:articleSlug", function(req, res, next) {
    articlesP.then(articleSet => {
        // dynamically check if this route matches a known article slug
        if (articleSet.has(req.param.articleSlug)) {
            articleRoute(req, res, next);
        } else {
            // no match found, just call next()
            next();
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Then, you have to edit `articleRoute()` to expect the actual article name not as the start of the path, but as `req.param.articleSlug` or as the second path element.

Note, this could also allow you to add and remove articles dynamically without restarting the server.

Comment: I actually tried the first one and it seems to just give 404s for all the articles, though I would be fine with them not loading until a few seconds after

Comment: @stackers - Then, there's something else going on that you aren't showing us. There's no harm in exporting the `app` object and then at some short time later adding routes to it and that's what your first one is doing.  That will work.  We'd have to see reproducible code that we could run to help you debug that if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @stackers - Unless you're adding generic routes AFTER and the order of your routes matters.  Then, your generic routes would get hit before your article routes.  You don't show that happening, but that's a theoretical cause of a problem.  Showing more code would allow us to see.  FYI, I strongly dislike the structure you're using where every article route is a top level route.  That leads to potential clashes between article slugs and ANY top level route you want your web-site to have.  It sounds like bugs waiting to happen as features are added to the site in the future.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I went out of my way to show several different ways this could be coded.  Is anything here inaccurate?

Comment: @stackers - I added some more explanation to my answer and comments about why your first one might not work (because of code you haven't shown us).